# python socket server persistent session connection handling

Tags: python, sockets, http

I am trying to implement an HTTP socket server in python.
Up to now al works great except one thing:
In my first design I made that every client request opens a new request handler thread whic means -
no persistent connection.
I want to support keep alive connection - all the request/response on the same tcp stream.

I can't put my code here because it's not approachable to me right now (other computer), but the conecpt is that:

```
while 1:
    #accept connections from outside
    (clientsocket, address) = serversocket.accept()
    #now do something with the clientsocket
    #in this case, we'll pretend this is a threaded server
    ct = client_thread(clientsocket)
    ct.run()
```

Comment: TCP connections *are* persistent. Once you have a connection it stays connected until there is an error or it's closed. You can have a TCP connection open with no traffic at all for days if you want to.

Comment: Also, you can't have multiple TCP streams on one connection, it's simply not designed that way.